# How to query specific dates in JavaScript on Sqlite database

Tags: javascript, sqlite, date

SQLite in combination with JavaScript gives me a hard time on dates.

For clarity I'm inserting a date "01-01-1999" using:

```
var yy =  "01-01-1999";
var yyy = new Date (yy.replace( /(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{4})/, "$3-$2-$1") );  //date into YYYY-MM-DD format

db.transaction (function (transaction) 
{
  var sql = "INSERT INTO happyPeople (datum, name, event) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
  transaction.executeSql (sql, [yyy, fNameIn, fEventIn], function ()
  { 
    alert (fNameIn + " inserted with date " + yyy );
  }, error);
```

Looking in the db shows indeed "Fri Jan 01 1999 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)"

but...

when I query for the same day (01-01-1999) with

```
var sql = "SELECT * FROM happyPeople WHERE datum  = strftime ('%Y-%m-%d','1999-01-01')";
```

I get no results meaning no error but an empty return list. If I replace the '=' to '!=' I get all the entries, so it seems the query works.
The field in the SQLite db that's holding the date is defined as VARCHAR[50] but I tried TEXT as well. Same result.

So, How do I insert a date (not interested in time) into the database and how to query them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has not separate data type for dates; you use [a string or a number](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime).

You correctly converted the string into `yyyy-mm-dd` format.
What is wrong with the code is that it then creates a `Date` object.
As you can see from the message, `yyy` is not a string in the correct format.

Just remove the `new Date`, and use the string directly.

Comment: And indeed that worked. I'm not sure if I understand but, yes I can query now. Thanks